# Данные создаются в несуществующей таблице "People"

Tags: sql, node.js

Хочу создать пользователя, но при отправке запроса выводится в консоль ошибка, что отношения People не существует.

```
original: error: отношение "People" не существует
```

### Модель пользователя

```
const sequelize = require("../db");
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const Person = sequelize.define("Person", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  surname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});

module.exports = Person;
```

### Controller пользователя

```
const Person = require("../models/Person");

class UserController {
  async createUser(req, res) {
    const { name, surname } = req.body;

    await Person.create({
      name,
      surname
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ ok: true, Persons: await Person.findAll() });
  }
}

module.exports = new UserController();
```

### Router пользователя

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require("../controllers/user.controller");

router.post("/user", userController.createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Работаю с таблицами post и person

Comment: Вы хотите сказать у вас ни в коде ни в базе нигде не упоминается слово People - а в консоли ошибка о нем?

Comment: @Mira, да, все верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно ваша орм система автоматически пытается угадать имя таблицы в которую сложить модель, person -> people , попробуйте вывести имя таблицы для вашей модели - что то вроде `person.Model.getTableName()` , и там будет people. Тогда указать имят аблицы надо в явном виде.

Comment: Я изменил модель Person

`const Person = sequelize.define("person", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  surname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
}, { tableName: "person" });`

И добавил ей название `person`. Сейчас у меня вылезла другая ошибка: `столбец "createdAt" в таблице "person" не существует`

Comment: По умолчанию ваша орм ожидает работать с полем "дата создания", эта опция отключается в конфиге var config = {
"define": {
    whatever: req.body.whatever,
    ...
  } ,{
    timestamps: false
}
}

Если мой ответ помог разрешить ошибку из вопроса, пометьте его правильным пожалуйста.